# discord.py give role on game activity

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot that would give a role when someone's playing a game.
for example someone plays CSGO, the bot would give him CSGO role while playing the game.
I can't seem to figure it out.

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if after.activity != before.activity:
        role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=after.activity)
        if role == None:
            await create_role(name=after.activity, hoist=True)
        await after.add_roles(role)
    elif before.activity != after.activity and not after.activity:
        role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=after.activity)
        if role in after.roles: 
            await after.remove_roles(role)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the game that a member is playing in the [`on_member_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_update#discord.on_member_update) event. For this you will need to check the [`Member.activity`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=activity#discord.Member.activity) parameter.

It would be something like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    games = ["game1", "game2", "game3"]
    if after.activity and after.activity.name.lower() in games:
            # Assuming the role name is the same as the game
            role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=after.activity)
            await after.add_roles(role)
    elif before.activity and before.activity.name.lower() in games and not after.activity:
            role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=after.activity)
            if role in after.roles: 
                await after.remove_roles(role)
```

#### References:

- [`on_member_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_update#discord.on_member_update)
- [`Member.activity`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=activity#discord.Member.activity)

Comment: I want the bot to create the role and then removes it after member activity is none

Comment: I updated the code adding the necessary `elif` statement to check and delete the role once the activity is none.

Comment: is there a way to do this without having to declare the games variable?
so the bot would see the game activity name and do declare it itself

Comment: You could make the bot directly assign the role corresponding to the `activity`, or create it if it does not exist, but I would not recommend this as people tend to create custom activities and you would end up with hundreds of useless roles.

Comment: how would I do that exactly?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you already have all the tools to do that with my answer, Stackoverflow is not to ask people to code for you, it is to ask for guidance.

Comment: is there a way to check if a role with that name already exists?

Comment: You can check if `discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=after.activity)` returns `None`

Comment: what am i doing wrong here? (added code to question)

Comment: I tried adding print statement after ```if after.activity != before.activity:``` but doesnt seem to print when i change activities